# Showing continuity of integrals of Feller process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $\{P^x\}$ be the probability distribution for a Feller process $\{X\}_t$. Then, how does one show that 
$$F(x) = \int_Df(X_t)g(X_s)P^x(d\omega)\quad (\dagger)$$ is a continuous function of $x$ given continuous, bounded functions $f$ and $g$?

The Feller property immediately tells that $$G(x) = \int_Df(X_t)P^x(d\omega)$$ is continuous for such an $f$, but I do not see how to extend this to derive $(\dagger).$

Comment: Hmm. Suppose $r = t-s > 0$, and define $Z_u = (X_u, X_{u-r})$. Is it possible to show $Z$ is Feller? (This might be complete nonsense — apologies if so. This was the first idea that came to mind.)

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist the process $\{X\}$ itself is a $d$- dimensional process on $\mathbb{R}^d$, so I am not sure how to continue your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: assume wlog that $t>s$. By the Markov property,
$$
F(x) = E^x[f(X_t) g(X_s)] = E^x[ h(X_s)g(X_s)],
$$
where $h(x) = E^x[f(X_{t-s})]$.